# How do I add a driver to the list of those recognized by CayenneModeler?

Tags: sql-server, apache-cayenne

I'm new to Apache Cayenne, and I'm trying out my first project. I'm attempting to use the **Tools > Reengineer Database Schema** feature of CayenneModeler to reverse engineer a SQL Server database.

I attempted to create a new "Saved DataSource".  I selected "org.apache.cayenne.dba.sqlserver.SQLServerAdapter" from its list of Adapters, and CayenneModeler automatically filled in the JDBC Driver field and added an example DB URL. I modified the DB URL, provided the username/password, clicked "Continue", and then I get the following error:

> Driver load error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I assume this means that CayenneModeler does have a driver for sqlserver by default(?) But I don't see a way to point CayenneModeler to any other drivers...

Any Cayenne experts out there know what I might be doing wrong? Is there a way to give CayenneModeler the driver it needs, assuming that is the problem? Or if a missing driver isn't the problem, does anyone know what is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location for adding additional drivers is under **Tools > Preferences > ClassPath** (Windows) or **CayenneModeler > Preferences... > Classpath** (OSX).